# Страницы выдают 404 в Google Pagespeed Insights

Tags: opencart, http-status-code-404, pagespeed-insights

Сайт https://armoservis.ru выдает подобную ошибку при анализе любых страниц, кроме главной (например, https://armoservis.ru/about):

Lighthouse returned error: ERRORED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Не удалось загрузить страницу. Убедитесь, что URL введен правильно и сервер отвечает на все запросы. Код статуса: 404.

Сами же страницы в браузере открываются нормально, и во вкладке Network в инструментах разработчика 404 не выдает при загрузке. Сайт сделан на Opencart с модулем SEO PRO, мне кажется проблема с этим модулем, может кто уже сталкивался с этим?

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте настройки вашего Seo модуля. Скорее всего проблема кроется в том что для русских и иностранных страниц используются разные ЧПУ. Поэтому когда вы заходите из рф он забирает с базы данных русские ЧПУ и все корректно отрабатывает, а когда заходит иностранец (в вашем случае робот) - он забирает англоязычные ЧПУ, которые очевидно у Вас не заполнены и выдает 404 ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте следующие внешние вызовы веб-страницы О компании которые возвращают ошибку 404:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текстовая версия этого сообщения:

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
> chrome-extension://bhmmomiinigofkjcapegjjndpbikblnp/libs/bundle.min.js.map:
> HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME DevTools
> failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
> chrome-extension://bhmmomiinigofkjcapegjjndpbikblnp/libs/lodash.min.js.map:
> HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Проверьте **[следующие проблемы с ресурсами этой веб-страницы](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?view=fetch-info&id=5qjkmqZXFfMqhsVrsxE5kQ)**, которые заблокированы в вашем файле роботс:

> https://armoservis.ru/catalog/view/javascript/ajax.js Script  Googlebot
> blocked by robots.txt
>
> https://armoservis.ru/catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css Stylesheet  Googlebot
> blocked by robots.txt
>
> https://armoservis.ru/catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js   Script  Googlebot
> blocked by robots.txt
>
> https://armoservis.ru/catalog/view/javascript/common.js   Script  Googlebot
> blocked by robots.txt
>
> https://armoservis.ru/catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css   Stylesheet  Googlebot
> blocked by robots.txt
>
> https://armoservis.ru/catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js  Script  Googlebot
> blocked by robots.txt
>
> https://armoservis.ru/catalog/view/javascript/slider.js   Script  Googlebot
> blocked by robots.txt
>
> https://armoservis.ru/catalog/view/javascript/slider_main.js  Script  Googlebot
> blocked by robots.txt
>
> https://armoservis.ru/catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/mobile.css    Stylesheet  Googlebot
> blocked by robots.txt
>
> https://armoservis.ru/catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/mobile_main.css   Stylesheet  Googlebot
> blocked by robots.txt
>
> https://armoservis.ru/catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/mobile_user.css   Stylesheet  Googlebot
> blocked by robots.txt
>
> https://armoservis.ru/catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/stylesheet.css    Stylesheet  Googlebot
> blocked by robots.txt

Проверьте **[следующие высказывания Гугл о файле роботс](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=ru)**:

> **Ограничения при использовании файла robots.txt**
>
> Прежде чем создавать
> или изменять файл robots.txt, примите во внимание риски, связанные с
> этим методом. Иногда для запрета индексирования определенных URL лучше
> применять другие решения.
>
> Директивы robots.txt поддерживаются не всеми поисковыми системами
> Директивы в файлах robots.txt не имеют обязывающей силы. Googlebot и
> большинство других поисковых роботов следуют инструкциям robots.txt,
> однако некоторые системы могут игнорировать их. Чтобы надежно защитить
> информацию от поисковых роботов, воспользуйтесь другими способами –
> например, парольной защитой файлов на сервере.
>
> **Обратите внимание**: одновременное применение нескольких методов может
> привести к конфликтам. Подробнее о настройке этих параметров можно
> узнать в статье на сайте Google Developers.

Также может помогать проверка **[следующих внешних ресурсов этой веб-страницы, которые возвращают ошибки 404](https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/https/armoservis.ru/about)**:

> Scan Failed https://armoservis.ru/about
>
> Unable to scan your site. 404 Not Found
>
> Site Issue Detected http://armoservis.ru/about
>
> Unable to scan the page. 404 Not Found
>
> Site Issue Detected https://armoservis.ru/.git/HEAD
>
> Unable to scan the page. 405 Method Not Allowed
>
> Site Issue Detected https://armoservis.ru/checkout
>
> Unable to scan the page. 404 Not Found
>
> Site Issue Detected https://armoservis.ru/login
>
> Unable to scan the page. 404 Not Found
>
> Site Issue Detected https://armoservis.ru/register
>
> Unable to scan the page. 404 Not Found
>
> Site Issue Detected https://armoservis.ru/wishlist
>
> Unable to scan the page. 404 Not Found

Обратите внимание на следующие устаревшие ресурсы этой веб-страницы:

> Outdated Software Detected PHP under 7.4.6
>
> Supported PHP Versions Outdated Software Detected OpenCart under
> 3.0.3.6
>
> Download the Latest Release

Попробуйте максимально минимизировать ваши запрещающие директивы в файле роотс и обновите программное обеспечение вашего веб-сайта.